# Somar valores de textboxes ao sair do campo

Tags: c#

Eu tenho um `form` com três `TextBoxes` onde o usuário digitará qualquer valor
e um `Label` onde quero mostrar o resultado da soma desses valores.

Porém, eu gostaria de ir somando o conteúdo dessas `TextBoxes` sem ter que clicar em um botão. Digo, enquanto eu estiver preenchendo os `TextBoxes`, os valores vão sendo somados e a soma é mostrada no `Label`.

Comment: você ja fez a rotina que efetua o calculo? pode chama-la na saida do ultimo textbox, no evento `onExit()` ou similiar.

Comment: Dessa forma ele executaria a rotina após o usuário clicar fora da txtbox?

Comment: o TextChanged() Tambem é uma boa ideia... mas pense que se o text estiver nulo, sem texto, ao transformar em inteiro, ele vai dar um erro, então incialmente é recomendado voce verificar se o valor estao nulo e considerar como zero ou nao calcular.

Comment: Isso já esta tudo pronto, se for igual a nulo ele considera 0 . então  esse método textchanged executara qnd ele clicar fora ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void fazOqVcQuer()
    {
        try
        {
            label1.Text =
            (Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text)
            +
            Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text)
            +
            Convert.ToDecimal(textBox3.Text)).ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }  
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fazOqVcQuer();
    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fazOqVcQuer();
    }

    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fazOqVcQuer();
    }
}
```

Olá amigo. Tem várias formas de se fazer isso. Já que você está iniciando, entenda este código "bem" simples. substitua os valores "textBox1", "textBox2" e "textBox3" pelo nome dos seus, etc

Comment: Não precisa declarar três eventos que fazem a mesma coisa, esse código está muito repetitivo. Você pode usar o mesmo evento para vários `TextBoxes` diferentes.

Comment: Outra coisa, não use aquele bloco `catch` vazio. Ou você usa o `catch` para **realmente** tratar as exceções ou você deixa o erro "estourar".

Comment: Ele mencionou ter recém começado a programar.

Comment: Por isso mesmo, deveria mostrar-lhe a forma certa de fazer as coisas.

Comment: Aahh entendi. Faz um método que some as duas txt box (convertendo pra int por exemplo) e manda mostrar o resultado no label. E usa o evento text_changed( q seria qnd o txtbox n estiver selecionado) para chamar o método. Eh isso?  E no catch poderia colocar " digite apenas números" eh isso pessoal?

Comment: TextChanged - cada caractere modificado/inserido no textbox acionará o evento.
E no catch, sim você pode colocar isso.